# Exceptions from Excel API after downgrading from 2013 to 2010

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2010

After downgrading from Excel 2013 to 2010 (i.e. removing 2013 and installing 2010) when I try to access the Excel OM from my add-in like this:

```
if (this.Application.ActiveWorkbook == null)
{
    return;
}
```

I get the following Exception:

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface
>   type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application'. This operation
>   failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the
>   interface with IID '{000208D5-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due
>   to the following error: Library not registered. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED)).

I have taken the following steps to resolve the issue but none have worked:

- Repaired the office installation
- Uninstalled and reinstalled
- Cleared out all office 15 references from the registry
- Re-registered Excel ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\excel.exe" /o)

However, nothing seems to work. Is there something I'm missing or do I actually have to wipe the machine?

EDIT:
My guess is that there is still come conflict in the registry but I have no idea where...

Thanks in adv!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution - I forgot to remove one reference to Excel 2013:

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib{00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\1.8

After removing `1.8` my corrected registry looks like this:

[image]

...

[image]

Credit: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/Thread/203666/unable-to-cast-com-object-of-type-microsoft-office-inte.aspx

Comment: Excellent! works perfectly with downgrades from 2010 to 2007 too!